# updating live tile image with background task image not showing

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm having some major issues getting a live tile to update its image via background task, I have tried it from a web server and from local files stored in the background agent but with no luck. If I change the tile count or tile then they work fine, the image does not. I have set them as content too, I don't see any reason why they don't.

here's my code:

```
    private void updateTile()
    {
        int date = DateTime.Now.Day;
        ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
        Uri here = new Uri("24.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        if (tile != null)
        {
            if (Settings.ListOpened.Value[date] == false)
            {
                StandardTileData data = new StandardTileData();
                data.BackgroundImage = here;
                data.Title = "Help";
                data.Count = 4;
                tile.Update(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is 24.jpg a 173x173 pixel image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the specific images (all 173*173px), `right-click -> properties -> in Build Action select Content` instead of resource. This will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Note that images used in tiles should be in IsolatedStorage in the `Shared/ShellContent/` directory.

Your issue is almost certainly the relative path of the image. When specifying paths it's always best to start with the forward slash from the root.